# Absolute positioning and Z-Index stacking

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I am trying to recreate so called `skill-cirle` which is popular in CV templates.

Like this

[image]

I am trying to achieve this using following code, I hope you will get an idea.

**CSS**

```
/* +++++ SKILL MODULES +++++ */
.skill-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center; }
  .skill-item__title {
    color: #494949; }
  .skill-item__circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #52b3d9;
    overflow: hidden; }
    .skill-item__circle-progress {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 66px;
      background-color: #68c3a3; }
    .skill-item__circle-percent {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: #494949; }

/* ----- SKILL MODULES ----- */
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="skill-item item">
                            <div class="skill-item__circle">
                                <div class="skill-item__circle-progress" data-percent="66"></div>
                                <div class="skill-item__circle-percent">66%</div>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="">HTML5 + CSS3</h4>
                        </div>
```

Here is my result

[image]

And [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/CROSP/znc6wk36/)

As you can see my `absolute positioned` block overlays text block, but I need this to work vice versa. Percent text with stacked on top of the `background progress block`.

How can I achieve this ?

I would be grateful for any help or suggestion how to do this better.

Comment: From this question alone, I feel like your circle is a little too full for HTML5 + CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `postion: relative;` to .`skill-item__circle-percent` and there you go!

```
.skill-item__circle-percent {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #494949;
  position: relative;
}
```

Please let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
.skill-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.skill-item__title {
  color: #494949;
}
.skill-item__circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #52b3d9;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.skill-item__circle-progress {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
  background-color: #68c3a3;
}
.skill-item__circle-percent {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #494949;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-item item">
  <div class="skill-item__circle">
    <div class="skill-item__circle-progress" data-percent="66"></div>
    <div class="skill-item__circle-percent">66%</div>
  </div>
  <h4 class="">HTML5 + CSS3</h4>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
This solution works as positioned elements (that are not static) are displayed above the elements that are not (static).

Comment: Thanks, the `position` property is the key.

Comment: Could you please explain, why I got such behavior, without specifying `position`, this because of default `static` ?

Comment: I guess so because positioned elements (that are not static) are displayed above the elements that are not (static).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. If you just add position/z-index you can place anything on anything.

https://jsfiddle.net/znc6wk36/1/

```
.skill-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center; }
  .skill-item__title {
    color: #494949; }
  .skill-item__circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #52b3d9;
    overflow: hidden; }
    .skill-item__circle-progress {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 66px;
      background-color: #68c3a3; }
    .skill-item__circle-percent {
      position: relative;
      display: table-cell;
      width: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: #494949; 
      z-index: 10;}

<div class="skill-item">
  <div class="skill-item__circle">
    <div class="skill-item__circle-progress" data-percent="66"></div>
    <div class="skill-item__circle-percent">66%</div>
  </div>
  <h4 class="">HTML5 + CSS3</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. By the way `z-index` doesn't work without `position` property.